# unexpected tikz style behaviour

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I was doing a figure based on drawing some rectangles which the area represents the relative amount of such element and I encounter two unexpected situations:

(1) I decided to go with rectangles to draw the figure (shown here below). Once I've finished the drawing I was willing to apply the style in order to obtain round edges and put them in white. Then I got the surprise that it can not be applied a style to the rectangles.

(2) The way I was building up the legend doesn't work since when the node is created using positioning the drawing cursor doesn't move from the origin.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,array,colortbl,siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} %Please, no page numbers or similar

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,yscale=-1]

% Defining stuff
\def\sep{0}
\definecolor{auxColori}{RGB}{124,121,247}
\definecolor{FAcolor}{RGB}{222,209,111}
\definecolor{Hcolor}{RGB}{146,209,105}
\definecolor{Gcolor}{RGB}{113,130,227}
\definecolor{CDIcolor}{RGB}{242,162,121}
\definecolor{CLIcolor}{RGB}{93,186,172}
\definecolor{CIDcolor}{RGB}{204,102,201}
\definecolor{Othercolor}{RGB}{191,96,124}
\definecolor{auxColor}{RGB}{120,190,240}
\definecolor{Qcolor}{RGB}{255,128,128}

% Drawing the rectangles
\draw [fill=Othercolor] (0,0) ++(-2.5,0) rectangle +(4.5,4);%18 other

\pgfmathsetmacro{\CIDheight}{7/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CLIheight}{12/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CDIheigth}{2*\sep+4+\CIDheight+\CLIheight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CDIwidth}{67/\CDIheigth}
\draw [fill=CIDcolor] (0,{\sep+4}) rectangle +(2,\CIDheight);% 7 CID
\draw [fill=CLIcolor] (0,{2*\sep+4+\CIDheight}) rectangle +(2,\CLIheight);%12 CLI
\draw [fill=CDIcolor] ({2+\sep},0) rectangle +(\CDIwidth,\CDIheigth);%67  CDI

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Gheight}{8/2.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Hheight}{6/2.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\FAheight}{2*\sep+4+\Gheight+\Hheight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\FAwidth}{69/\FAheight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Qwidth}{\sep+2.5+\FAwidth}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Qheight}{90/\Qwidth}
\draw [fill=Gcolor] (0,{\sep+4}) rectangle +(-2.5 ,\Gheight);% 8 G              
\draw [fill=Hcolor]  (0,{2*\sep+4+\Gheight}) rectangle +(-2.5,\Hheight);%6 H
\draw [fill=FAcolor] ({-2.5+\sep},0) rectangle +(-\FAwidth,\FAheight);%69 FA
\draw [fill=Qcolor] (0,{\FAheight+\sep}) rectangle +(-\Qwidth,\Qheight);%90 Q


% Creating the legend
\tikzset{nameSt/.style={anchor=west}}
\draw[draw=Qcolor, fill=Qcolor] (10,0) node[nameSt] (Qname) {Q} ++(-.5,-.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
\draw[draw=FAcolor, fill=FAcolor] node[nameSt, below=of Qname] (FAname) {FA} ++(-.5,-.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
\draw[draw=Gcolor, fill=Gcolor] node[nameSt, below=of FAname] (Gname) {G} ++(-.5,-.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: figure]

Any hints?

Comment: Can you reproduce your unexpected behavior in a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution for rectangles with rounded corners using style

```
\tikzset{
wrcorners/.style = {rounded corners=6pt,line width=1.8pt,draw=white}
}
```

and nodes for the legend

```
\tikzset{nameSt/.style=
{anchor=west,rectangle,
 minimum width=10pt,minimum height=10pt,
}}
\draw[] (8,1) node[nameSt,draw=Qcolor, fill=Qcolor,label=right:Q] (Qname) {};
\draw[] node[nameSt, draw=FAcolor, fill=FAcolor,below=of Qname,label=right:FA] (FAname) {} ;
\draw[] node[nameSt,draw=Gcolor, fill=Gcolor, below=of FAname,label=right:G] (Gname) {};
```

The result is

[image: Rounded corners + legend]

Here's the full code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,array,colortbl,siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{
    wrcorners/.style = {rounded corners=6pt,line width=1.8pt,draw=white}
}


\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty} %Please, no page numbers or similar

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3,yscale=-1]

% Defining stuff
\def\sep{0}
\definecolor{auxColori}{RGB}{124,121,247}
\definecolor{FAcolor}{RGB}{222,209,111}
\definecolor{Hcolor}{RGB}{146,209,105}
\definecolor{Gcolor}{RGB}{113,130,227}
\definecolor{CDIcolor}{RGB}{242,162,121}
\definecolor{CLIcolor}{RGB}{93,186,172}
\definecolor{CIDcolor}{RGB}{204,102,201}
\definecolor{Othercolor}{RGB}{191,96,124}
\definecolor{auxColor}{RGB}{120,190,240}
\definecolor{Qcolor}{RGB}{255,128,128}

% Drawing the rectangles
\draw [fill=Othercolor,wrcorners] (0,0) ++(-2.5,0) rectangle +(4.5,4);%18 other
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CIDheight}{7/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CLIheight}{12/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CDIheigth}{2*\sep+4+\CIDheight+\CLIheight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\CDIwidth}{67/\CDIheigth}
\draw [fill=CIDcolor,wrcorners] (0,{\sep+4}) rectangle +(2,\CIDheight);% 7 CID
\draw [fill=CLIcolor,wrcorners] (0,{2*\sep+4+\CIDheight}) rectangle +(2,\CLIheight);%12 CLI
\draw [fill=CDIcolor,wrcorners] ({2+\sep},0) rectangle +(\CDIwidth,\CDIheigth);%67  CDI

\pgfmathsetmacro{\Gheight}{8/2.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Hheight}{6/2.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\FAheight}{2*\sep+4+\Gheight+\Hheight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\FAwidth}{69/\FAheight}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Qwidth}{\sep+2.5+\FAwidth}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Qheight}{90/\Qwidth}
\draw [fill=Gcolor,wrcorners] (0,{\sep+4}) rectangle +(-2.5 ,\Gheight);% 8 G              

\draw [fill=Hcolor,wrcorners]  (0,{2*\sep+4+\Gheight}) rectangle +(-2.5,\Hheight);%6 H
\draw [fill=FAcolor,wrcorners] ({-2.5+\sep},0) rectangle +(-\FAwidth,\FAheight);%69 FA
\draw [fill=Qcolor,wrcorners] (0,{\FAheight+\sep}) rectangle +(-\Qwidth,\Qheight);%90 Q

% Creating the legend
%\tikzset{nameSt/.style={anchor=west}}
%\draw[draw=Qcolor, fill=Qcolor] (10,0) node[nameSt] (Qname) {Q} ++(-.5,-.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
%\draw[draw=FAcolor, fill=FAcolor] node[nameSt, below=of Qname] (FAname) {FA} ++(-.5,-.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);
%\draw[draw=Gcolor, fill=Gcolor] node[nameSt, below=of FAname] (Gname) {G} ++(-.5,-.5) rectangle +(.5,.5);

% Creating the legend
\tikzset{nameSt/.style=
{anchor=west,rectangle,
minimum width=10pt,minimum height=10pt,
}}
\draw[] (8,1) node[nameSt,draw=Qcolor, fill=Qcolor,label=right:Q] (Qname) {};
\draw[] node[nameSt, draw=FAcolor, fill=FAcolor,below=of Qname,label=right:FA] (FAname) {} ;
\draw[] node[nameSt,draw=Gcolor, fill=Gcolor, below=of FAname,label=right:G] (Gname) {}; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```